# getting some error while putting some dataframes in TA-Lib library, don't know what to do next

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ta-lib

I was putting some dataframe in the ta-lib library to detect engulfing pattern but this error shows up which i don't know what it means please help

```
import pandas as pd
import talib as tb

bnkin = pd.read_csv("BANKINDIA.csv")
print(bnkin)

integer = tb.CDLENGULFING(bnkin['open'], bnkin['high'], bnkin['low'], bnkin['close'])
print(integer)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3081, in get_loc   
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'open'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/myads/OneDrive/Desktop/technical_analysis/TAprg.py", line 29, in <module>
    integer = tb.CDLENGULFING(bnkin['open'], bnkin['high'], bnkin['low'], bnkin['close'])
  File "C:\Users\myads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__      
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\myads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3083, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'open'
```

[BANKINDIA.csv:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJeTw.png)

Comment: Can you add a preview of BANKINDIA.csv and what is tb.CDLENGULFING()? Please show imported modules as well

Comment: @DSteman I've added the  imported modules and screenshot of BANKINDIA.csv. tb.CDLENGULFING() is a pattern recognition function kindly go to [link](http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/pattern_recognition.html)  for reference

Comment: Agree with @DSteman. All the column's initials are capitals. This should work:
integer = tb.CDLENGULFING(bnkin['Open'], bnkin['High'], bnkin['Low'], bnkin['Close'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a column 'open', but your csv has a column 'Open', hence the key error.